# asyncio doesn't work because it doesnt have the attribute '_DEBUG'

Tags: python, discord, bots, python-asyncio

I'm trying to create a discord bot, which displays the stats of r6 players. but when trying to start it, it displays the error:

> AttributeError: module 'asyncio.coroutines' has no attribute '_DEBUG'

I tried to solve it but nothing has worked.

Edit: I have tried around a little bit with different IDE's etc. it doesn't seem to be a problem with the code but rather with the asyncio library

Here is the code

```
import random
import r6statsapi


def handle_response(message) -> str:
    p_message = message.lower()
    client = r6statsapi.Client('TOKEN')

    if p_message == 'hello':
        return 'Hey there!'

    if p_message == 'roll':
        return str(random.randint(1, 6))
    
    if p_message == '!help':
        return "`No help yet ;(`"
    
    name = ''
    if p_message == f'!stats {name}':
        return f"Here you go ;) {client.get_generic_stats(name, r6statsapi.Platform.uplay)}"
```

Comment: Whatever the problem is, it's in your `róstatsapi` module. Nothing in the code shown uses `asyncio` at all.

Comment: I have tried using another API called r6stats but it is giving me the same error ;(

Comment: What version of Python are you using?